# How to get model attributes within a view in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I am trying to pass a model as parameter in a view.
I am getting my object in the view, but no way to access its attributes...
Here is the code :

From the router :

```
var Product = new ProductModel({id: id});
Product.fetch();
var product_view = new ProductView({el: $("#main-content"), model: Product});
```

From the model :

```
var ProductModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot: 'http://192.168.1.200:8080/store/rest/product/'
});
```

From the view :

```
ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log(this.model);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        var options = {
            id: this.model.id,
            name: this.model.get('name'),
            publication_start_date: this.model.get('publication_start_date'),
            publication_end_date: this.model.get('publication_end_date'),
            description: this.model.get('description'),
            applis_more: this.model.get('applis_more')
        }
        var element = this.$el;
        var that = this;
        $.get('templates/product.html', function(data){
            var template = _.template(data, options);
            element.html(template);
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the result of the "console.log":

```
child {attributes: Object, _escapedAttributes: Object, cid: "c1", changed: Object, _silent: Object…}
Competences: child
Editor: child
Hobbies: child
Opinions: child
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_pending: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
_silent: Object
attributes: Object
createdDate: null
deletedDate: null
descriptionId: 0
galleryImage: null
id: 13
image: null
manufacturerId: 0
name: "sdf"
owner: 0
status: 0
thumbnail: null
titleId: 0
type: 1
uid: "fdsf"
updatedDate: null
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c1"
id: 13
__proto__: ctor
```

In my view, all my options are "undefined" (name, dates,...)

Any idea on what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I suspect that your issue is that [fetch](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch) is asynchronous and therefore when you pass the model it hasn't been fetched yet, try using the success callback.

Comment: But then how in my console.log(this.model) can I see my Product model with attributes correctly filled ?

Comment: @PierrickFlajoulot `console.log` is not a typical print statement - it is a living reference to that object (at least in Chrome). If the object changes, the previous output of a `console.log` will also change.

Comment: @AbeVoelker I remembered seeing a answer here on SO about that and was in middle of looking for that post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After creating the initial model, you're immediately creating the view using

```
var product_view = new ProductView({..., model: Product});
```

In the `initialize` method of `ProductView`, you're calling `this.render()`, which in turn reads and renders values from the model - most of these values are `undefined` (because the server did not have sufficient time to send back the model's values).
Don't call `this.render()` directly, but bind an event, eg:

```
// in ProductView::initialize
this.model.on('sync', function() {
    this.render();
}, this);
```

You might also want to bind the `change` event, so that local (not synchronizsed yet) changes to the model are also reflected in the view. (An overview of Backbone events can be found [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the point except it was `this.model.on` rahter than `this.on` ;)
Now working fine !

Comment: Geeeeeee... Am I happy I found this answer????!!!! I've been scratching my hair for the last 3 hours trying to figure out why my connection to my REST-service didn't work. The 'sync' event saved my day:) Again many thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Because Product.fetch() happens asynchronously, you'll want to create the view once the data has been retrieved from the server:

```
var Product = new ProductModel({id: id});
var product_view;
Product.fetch().done(function() {
    product_view = new ProductView({el: $("#main-content"), model: Product});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Product.fetch() is an asynchronous call, so my guess is that the fetch has not completed yet when you initialize the view.  What you probably want to do is use fetch's success + error callbacks, to assure the model has data in it before rendering anything

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch